# Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare() Graphhopper

Tags: android, background-thread, graphhopper

I ran into following error.

```
logUser("An error happend while creating graph:"+ getErrorMessage());
```

Where getErrorMessage() is Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare() and logUser is a function which just show toast congaing message.

```
void prepareGraph() {
    logUser("loading graph (" + Helper.VERSION + "|" + Helper.VERSION_FILE
            + ") ... ");
    new MyAsyncTask<Void, Void, Path>() {
        protected Path saveDoInBackground(Void... v) throws Exception {
            GraphHopper tmpHopp = new GraphHopper().forAndroid();
            tmpHopp.contractionHierarchies(true);
            tmpHopp.load(mapsFolder + currentArea);
            logUser("found graph with " + tmpHopp.getGraph().nodes() + " nodes");
            hopper = tmpHopp;
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Path o) {
            if (hasError()) {
                logUser("An error happend while creating graph:"
                        + getErrorMessage());
            } else {
                logUser("Finished loading graph. Touch to route.");
                calcPath(52.534185, 13.348732, 52.53857,
                        13.41259);
            }

            finishPrepare();
        }
    }.execute();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant do UI operations from background thread.

Try this:

```
GraphHopper tmpHopp = new GraphHopper().forAndroid();
tmpHopp.contractionHierarchies(true);
tmpHopp.load(mapsFolder + currentArea);
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {    
    public void run() {
        logUser("found graph with " + tmpHopp.getGraph().nodes() + " nodes");
    }
});
hopper = tmpHopp;
return null;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to instantiate your `AsyncTask` on the main thread. The `AsyncTask` source code creates a `Handler` to call your `onPreExecute()`, `onPostExecute()`, etc. methods, and if that `Handler` is not instantiated on the main thread, Android will throw an exception telling you that the thread that `Handler` is interacting with has not had it's `Looper.prepare()` method called.